# How to enable "Use Default Value" for product attribute programmatically?

Tags: magento

Did somebody know how can I enable programmatically "Use Default Value" for a product attribute in second StoreView so that Magento uses the value from the default StoreView?

I tried following code but this doesn´t work:

```
$soap->call($sessionId, 'product.update', array($sku, array('color_addition'=>''), 'gb'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Use Default Values" for the attribute value by passing false.

```
$soap->call($sessionId, 'product.update', 
array($sku, array('color_addition'=>false), 'gb'));
```